# Can't Get Data in String Regexp

Tags: c#, regex

Trying to get X in `|[ID:X] text|`.

But i can't do right pattern.

X can be Num And Word.

```
string pattern = "([ID:(.?)^])";
```

Comment: `"|[ID:X] text|".Split('[', ']').Where(p => p.StartsWith("ID:")).FirstOrDefault().Substring(3);`

Comment: But if we have [ID:]  How prevent error?

Comment: Саша, What error do you get with `[ID:]` input? `"[ID:]".Split('[', ']').Where(p => p.StartsWith("ID:")).FirstOrDefault().Substring(3);` returns an empty string. You can surely check if `ID:` is there at all: `var res = string.Empty;
            var val = s.Split('[', ']').Where(p => p.StartsWith("ID:")).FirstOrDefault();
            if (val != null)  res = val.Substring(3);`

Comment: Or do you need to delete `[ID:X]`?

Answer (score 0):

> Trying to get `X` in `|[ID:X] text|`.

You may just split the string with `[` and `]`, get the part that starts with `ID:` and obtain what is after it:

```
var s = "|[ID:X] text|";
var res = string.Empty;
var val = s.Split('[', ']').Where(p => p.StartsWith("ID:")).FirstOrDefault();
if (val != null)
    res = val.Substring(3);
```

A regex solution (bearing in mind that *`X` can be Num And Word*):

```
\[ID:(\w*)]
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%5BID%3A(%5Cw*)%5D&i=%7C%5BID%3AX%5D%20text%7C)

C# removing the `[ID:...]` demo:

```
var res = Regex.Replace("|[ID:X] text|", @"\[ID:(\w*)]", string.Empty); 
// => | text|
```

C# demo showing how to get the `X`:

```
var res = string.Empty;
var m = Regex.Match("|[ID:X] text|", @"\[ID:(\w*)]");
if (m.Success)
   res = m.Groups[1].Value;
```